# What container to choose for fast search/insert with huge amounts of data?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, deque

So it's a thought experiment. I want to have a huge collection of structures such as:

```
struct
{
    KeyType key;
    ValueType value;
}
```

And I need fast access by a key and fast insertion of new values.

I would not use std::map cuz it has too big memory overhead for one structure and for huge amounts of data it might be drastical. Right?

So next I would consider using sorted std::vector and binary_search. It's fine for searching, but adding new values to the vector would be too slow. Imagine you need to add a new value to the beginning of the sorted array, you'd have to move data right aaaaaAAAALOT!

What if I use deque? As I know it has O(1) for push_back/push_front, but still O(n) for inserting (as it would have to move data anyway, less data though).

The questions are:

1) Is O(n) of inserting data in deque much faster in real situation than O(n) in vector?

2) What happens when you insert a value to Deque and the bucket it should go into is full?

3) Is there another preferable type of container in case you need to store lots of data and need two fast operations: search and insertion?

Thanks!

Comment: First specify the types of searches and the count of expected members and operations by type: inserts, removals, searches (of different type - nineth oldest, exact key, nearest key ...)

Comment: Although time complexity is important, memory hierarchy can dominate the performance too. The theoretical analysis can only narrow down our choice. Measurement is the only practical way to know for sure which one to choose.

Answer (score 4):

> I would not use std::map cuz it has too big memory overhead for one structure and for huge amounts of data it might be drastical. Right?

That depends on the size of your structs... the bigger they are the less the overheads are as a proportion of the overall memory use.  For example, a `std::map` implementation might average say 20 bytes of housekeeping data per element (I just made that up - measure on your own system), so if your struct size is in the hundreds of bytes - who cares...?  But, if the struct holds 2 `ints`, it's a big proportion....

> So next I would consider using sorted std::vector and binary_search. It's fine for searching, but adding new values to the vector would be too slow. Imagine you need to add a new value to the beginning of the sorted array, you'd have to move data right aaaaaAAAALOT!

Totally unsuitable....

> 1) Is O(n) of inserting data in deque much faster in real situation than O(n) in vector?

As `deque` is likely implemented as a vector of fixed-sized arrays, insertion implies a shuffling of all elements towards the nearest end of the container.  The shuffling's probably a tiny bit less cache efficient, but if inserting nearer the front of the container it would likely still end up faster.

2) What happens when you insert a value to Deque and the bucket it should go into is full?

As above, it'll need to shuffle, overflowing either:

- the last element to become the first element of the next "bucket", moving all those elements along and overflowing into the next bucket, etc.
- the first element to become the last element of the previous bucket, moving all those elements along and overflowing into the next bucket, etc.

> 3) Is there another preferable type of container in case you need to store lots of data and need two fast operations: search and insertion?

`unordered_map`, which is implemented as a hash map.  If you have small objects (e.g. less than 20 or 30 bytes) or a firm cap on the number of elements, you can normally easily outperform `unordered_map` with custom code, but it's rarely worth the effort unless the table access dominates you application's performance, and that performance is critical.

Answer (score 3):

> 3) Is there another preferable type of container in case you need to store lots of data and need two fast operations: search and insertion?

Consider using [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), which is an implementation of a hash map.  Insertion, lookup, and removal are all O(1) in the average case.  This assumes that you will only ever look for an item based on its exact key; if your searches can have different constraints then you either need a different structure, or you need multiple maps to map the various keys you will search for to the corresponding object.

This requires that there is an available hash function for `KeyType`, either as part of the standard library or provided by you.

Answer (score 2):

There's no container which would provide the best of all the worlds to you. Like you are saying you want best lookup/insertion with minimum amount of space needed for storing elements.

Below if the list of containers which you could consider for your implementation:-

VECTOR :-

Strengths:-

```
1) Space is allocated only for holding data. 
2) Good for random access.
3) Container of choice if insertions/deletions are not in the middle of the container.
```

Weakness:-

```
1) poor performance if insertions/deletions are at the middle.
2) rellocations happen if reserve is not used properly.
```

DEQUE:-

Choose deque over vector in case insertions/deletions are at the beginning as well as end of the container.

MAP:-

Disadvantage over vector:-

```
1) more space is allocated for holding pointers.
```

Advantages over vector:-

```
1) better insertions/deletions/lookup as compared to vector.
```

If `std::unordered_map` is used then these dictionary operations would be amortized O(1).

Comment: Another *big* advantage for deque compared to vector imho is that one avoid reallocation.

Comment: @geoalgo: are you sure about that? As far as I know, inserts and deletes inside the deque invalidate pointers and iterators, so reallocation would be allowed.

Comment: @MikeMB: geoalgo's over-stated the benefits, but there can be less dramatic reallocation, without moving existing elements, when pushing at the front or back.  Pointers/iterators can also be invalidated even without reallocation because elements are shuffled into different slots in the already allocated memory (much as with vector insert invalidating pointers/iterators to elements after the insertion point even when not reallocating).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in order to directly answer your questions:

> 1) Is O(n) of inserting data in deque much faster in real situation
>   than O(n) in vector?

The number of elements that have to be moved is (on average) only half compared to vector. However,  it can actually perform worse as the data is stored in non-contiguous  memory, so copying/moving the same number of elements is much less efficient (it cannot e.g. be implemented in terms of a single memcopy operation).

> 2) What happens when you insert a value to Deque and the bucket it
>   should go into is full?

At least for the gnu gcc Libstdc++ implementation, every bucket except the first and last one is always full. I believe, that inserting in the middle means that all elements are moved/copied one slot to the closer end (front or back) and the effect ripples through all buckets until the first or last one is reached.

In summary, the only scenario, where std::deque is consistently better than vector is if you use it as (suprise) a queue (only inserting and removing elements from the front or end) and that's what the implementation is optimized for. It is not optimized for insertions in the middle.

> 3) Is there another preferable type of container in case you need to
>   store lots of data and need two fast operations: search and insertion?

As already stated by others: A hash table like std::unordered_map is the data structure you are looking for.

From what I've heard however, std::unordered_map is a slightly suboptimal implementation if it, as it uses buckets in order to resolve hash collisions and those buckets are implemented as linked lists ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHNmRkzxHWs)  is a very interesting talk from Chandler Carruth on the general topic of the performance of different data structures). For random access on big data structures, cache locality should matter a lot less, so this is probably not such a big issue in your case.

Finally I'd like to mention that if your value and key types are small PODs and depending on how big your huge collection is (are we talking about some million or rather billions of elements) and how often you actually have to insert/remove elements, there might still be cases, where a simple std::vector outperforms any other STL container. So as always: if your thought experiment ever becomes reality try out and measure.